# Failure sending request: StatusCode=0 -- Original Error: Code="LinkedAuthorizationFailed"

Tags: azure, packer, packer-builder

I'm using Packer with Azure in order to create custom image Linux ubuntu.
The **source** image has been migreted from **other subscription** (zzzzz-zzzzz-zzzz-832e-zzzzzzzz) Azure which I don't have access ant put in my Gallery in **subscription xxxxx-xxxxx-xxxx-8757-xxxxxx**.

When trying to build, I'm getting the error:

`Build 'azure-chroot' errored after 9 seconds 112 milliseconds: error attaching disk '/subscriptions/xxxxx-xxxxx-xxxx-8757-xxxxxx/resourceGroups/aaaaaa-DEVOPS-NEXTGEN-DEV-RG/providers/Microsoft.Compute/disks/PackerTemp-osdisk-1648023954': compute.VirtualMachinesClient#CreateOrUpdate: Failure sending request: StatusCode=0 -- Original Error: Code="LinkedAuthorizationFailed" Message="The client 'iiiiiiii-iiii-iii-9087-bd35be0485c3' with object id 'iiiiii-iiii-iiii-9087-bd35be0485c3' has permission to perform action 'Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/write' on scope '/subscriptions/xxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-8757-xxxxxxx/resourceGroups/UAI3042788-DEVOPS-NEXTGEN-DEV-RG/providers/Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/aaaaaaa-devops-nextgen-internal-dev-ubuntu-01-vm'; however, it does not have permission to perform action 'read' on the linked scope(s) '/subscriptions/zzzzz-zzzzz-zzzz-832e-zzzzzzzz/resourceGroups/aaaaaaa-ren-common-prod-rg/providers/Microsoft.Compute/galleries/RenewablesSharedImageGallery/images/ren-azure-ubuntu-december-2021' or the linked scope(s) are invalid."`

My simple packer build file :

```
{
  "builders": [{
    "type": "azure-chroot",


    "image_resource_id": "/subscriptions/subscription_id/resourceGroups/resource_group/providers/Microsoft.Compute/images/PEOSLinuxImage",

    "source": "/subscriptions/xxxxx-xxxxx-xxxx-8757-xxxxxx/resourceGroups/aaaaaaa-devops-nextgen-dev-rg/providers/Microsoft.Compute/galleries/uai3042788nextgenImageGallery/images/
ren-azure-ubuntu/versions/1.0.03"


  }],
  "provisioners": [{
    "execute_command": "chmod +x {{ .Path }}; {{ .Vars }} sudo -E sh '{{ .Path }}'",
    "inline": [
      "apt-get update",
      "apt-get upgrade -y",
      "apt-get install openssh-server openssh-client -y"    
      
    ],
    "inline_shebang": "/bin/sh -x",
    "type": "shell"
  }]
}
```

Any help please?

Comment: So, the user/ sp executing the above packer code should have `read` access on source image id in source subscription & should have `VM Contributor` & write privileges on the subscription where you are creating images on azure compute gallery. Most importantly, both subscriptions should be part of the same tenant...